# How do I compare a number in a certain index from two different 2d arrays?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So this program starts by initializing two 2d arrays that are 4 by 4. the arrays are filled with random numbers between 9 and 0. I already did those methods, and they print correctly. then, i need to compare each number in those two using enhanced for loops ONLY. whichever one is bigger will print, creating a new array. I know how to do this with regular for loops, but how would do this? hopefully this makes sense. I don't even know where to start with this, honestly.

my instance variables are:

```
private int[][] matrix1 = new int[4][4]; //
private int[][] matrix2 = new int[4][4];
```

Comment: Is this java? Please tag appropriately

Comment: yes, it is java. i put it in the tags:)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[][] solve(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2) {
    // ignore matrix1 has same size with matrix2
    int[][] res = new int[matrix1.length][matrix1[0].length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix1[0].length; j++) {
            res[i][j] = Math.max(matrix1[i][j], matrix2[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```